# Select li, copy to another ul based on select - JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to practice the basics with this task.

I have a list of tasks, When you click on a task, a select shows (this is based on people in the html)

You select a person and then the task is added to that persons ul.

This is what I have so far:
fiddle has more comments:
http://jsfiddle.net/GavinSteele/Cfyjc/

```
<ul></ul>
```

Any help would be great.. code, or just direction on which tasks to do first.

```
// Click on a task
// Show select with peoples names
// Select a person
// Task is added to that persons ul

$(document).ready(function() {
  // populate the select with options    
  $(".person h4").each(function() {
    var optionTexts = [];
    optionTexts.push($(this).text());
    $('<option>').val(optionTexts).text(optionTexts).appendTo('select');
  });

// Get the selected person
  var selected = $('select :selected').text();

// Get the HTML of the task selected to append to the persons list
  $("#original li").click(function(){
    var html = $(this)[0].outerHTML;
    $("select").removeClass("hidden");
    $(html).appendTo(// THE SELECTED PERSONS LIST);

  });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).clone(true).appendTo(…)`? Do not use `outerHTML`

Comment: What's your problem? it seems this is a do-it-for-me

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, sorry this is not a do it for me post. I just need help in direction. Doesnt have to be code, maybe just, why have you done this.. try this.. Thanks @Bergi thats the type of thing I needed

Comment: @Bergi when I alert that in jsfiddle, I get [object, object], but my way I see the actual list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any help would be great.. code, or just direction on which tasks to do first.

here is a great help, closer to where you were. You will need to change two things, this appends task only if select is changed. You will need to do this,

1. Append even if an option is clicked/selected. i.e. even if Person A was the previous value and is again selected.
2. It appends the previous clicked task too. You will need to change so that it appends the clicked task only.

Here is **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfyjc/5/)**.

This is how you find the closest ul, searching for text matching in h4.

```
$(html).appendTo($('h4:contains("'+selected+'")').parents('ul').find('ul'));
```

Comment: Thanks @Optimus thats a great help

Comment: sorry refreshed and it wasnt green any more. Fixed now :)